# ASP.NET MVC and submitting different models to an Action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have a scenario where I have a list of filters that inherit from the same base class (`BaseFilter`).  This are rendered in a few with different templates in a certain order based on what the user chooses.  What is the best way to grab that data via javascript and submit it via an ajax request to a strongly typed `List<IBaseFilter>` in the `ActionResult`.  Should I use a model binder and if so how with a list of `IFilters`?

```
public ActionResult Save(List<IFilter> filters)
{
}

public FirstFilter : BaseFilter {
  // Has Two Properties
}

public SecondFilter : BaseFilter {
  // Has One Property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting from child to parent means that you loose all child properties, and you only get parent properties. If you model bind filters to `IFilter` then only properties existing in `IFilter` would be available to you. I recommend that you create two action methods, and save filters consecutively, if possible, and use strongly-typed model binding in those actions. Another options might be to send data to the action method, but extract information manually from HTTP request, rather than letting ASP.NET MVC bind incoming parameters to your `List<IFilter>` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Binders get what's in the FormCollection, and convert them to nice model objects for you. You probably can create a customized binder (IModelBinder implementation) to do all that for you. See [this post](http://develoq.net/2011/asp-net-mvc-model-binders-and-how-to-create-custom-model-binder/) to get an idea on how they work.